# How to delete/edit a quickbar item?

Tags: factorio

I'm a bit clumsy with the UI/hotkeys so I have several items on my quickbar that shouldn't be there. Because they're duplicates or just the wrong item.

How can I remove or edit these items?

This is about the new quickbar that came in .17.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default keybind is the Middle Mouse Button. Middle click on an item in the quickbar to remove it, and you can add a new item in that slot.

If you have no middle mouse button or just want to change it, it can be found in the controls menu under Inventory, Toggle Filter. Changing it to the right mouse button this way worked just fine and didn't conflict with anything.

Comment: If you're working on a laptop, and therefore probably have no middile-button, simultaneously press both the left- and right-buttons together to remove the item under the cursor from the hotbar.